# UIButton addtarget to a different view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm adding a `button` to a `view` on a different `ViewController`.  I need the target selector to point to that view controller:

```
//target is self which works only works where I created the button
testBTN.addTarget(self, action: "test:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

//otherVC is being instantiated as a new view controller so it doesn't work
testbtn.addTarget(otherVC(), action: "test:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

How can I get the target to point to an already existing `ViewController`(otherVC)?

Comment: You need a reference to it. I'm not sure where it exists in your navigation flow but you'll need to carry around a reference to it and then you can use it. Alternatively you can instantiate a new instance of it from the storyboard.

Comment: you can save a reference of the `otherVC`, from where everyone can access the latest instantiated `otherVC`.

Answer (score 2):

figured it out

```
let otherVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("otherIdentifier")
testbtn.addTarget(otherVC, action: "test:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```